# is there a way to use existing websites as an Android app?

Tags: android, mysql, web-applications

I need your expertise to understand how an Android App can communicate with an existing website.

- Using the same web interface but should be displayed as an Android app
- Using the same database, when we try searching, and the result should be displayed with in the app
- Using the same authentication, so if we accept username/password on our Android app, it should use an existing website script which can authenticate and whatever is returned should be displayed in the app.

Thanks

Comment: Here is example - you can buld parser on website (you can call it webservice) and it accepts parameters like this - http://example.com?device=android&tag=latestnews
In parser you query the database for latest news and create xml or json response where you have images, text, date,etc.
On android device you collect response parse it and assign to variables which you use to display data. I have build several news readers that work like this, I suggest using json because it is fast so your users wont have to wait long for loading and use caching on webservice side also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use webview for display of pages that should be optimized for best user experience on phone, you can query the database and show response on android - for that you need to build parser on webpage that can accept some sort of query and return response in for example json or xml format. The same goes for authentication, it is very simple actually

Comment: Thanks, this helped. One more quick one, WebView shows completely blank until the complete website content is fetched and displays, which to some users may feel like the app is doing nothing and they may immediately come out of the app. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can extend WebViewClient class and implement progressdialog for example that can show message that the page is loading so that user don't press back button just jet. I you need some more help just let me know

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you need to access Web Services of Website to take the data back from the Website to the App.